# Trying to save xml file from pdftables api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest-client

I'm trying to make a request to the PDFTables API, and save what is returned (an xml doc) in a new file. I have this code:

```
result = RestClient.post "https://pdftables.com/api?key=nn123450hsn", :myfile => File.new("./lib/assets/PeterValleyHexacoResults.pdf", "rb")

File.open('./lib/assets/test.xml', "w") do |f|
  f.puts result
end`
```

When I view the newly saved file, it looks like a bunch of random symbols and characters in the editor. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `f.puts result.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the result in XLSX format. You need to specify XML in your request:

```
result = RestClient.post "https://pdftables.com/api?key=nn123450hsn&format=xml", :myfile => File.new("./lib/assets/PeterValleyHexacoResults.pdf", "rb")
```